# Accessing session variable in the same php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, session-variables

I have an `index.php` in which I am logging in via email and password and the email id gets stored in a session variable. After logging in, a hidden `div` is visible and when clicked on it, I want the session variable of email to display on the same page. I'm saving the session like this in form-login.php:

```
$_SESSION['userEmail'] = $email_signin;
```

where `$email_signin` is the sign in email id captured from form in `index.php`.

When I echo this session, I can see the email getting displayed within this file.

I want this session to be accessed in my `index.php` as well. I have used `<?php echo $_SESSION['userEmail']; ?>`, but it gives me blank value.

I have used `session_start()` wherever necessary. Please help!

form-login.php
`

```
<?php
session_start();
try {
if(isset($_POST)){
    //echo("inside isset function");
$email_signin=$_POST['email2'];
}
    $_SESSION['userEmail'] = $email_signin;
    echo $email_signin;
    $_SESSION['logged'] = "yes";
    print_r($_POST);
    echo "Welcome $email_signin. Your session is set.";
    var_dump($_SESSION);
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    $_SESSION['login_error'] = $e->getMessage();
}
```

`

index.php
`

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['userEmail'])){
  $email_signin = $_SESSION['userEmail'];
  echo $_SESSION['userEmail']; 
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/style.css'; ?>">

<script>
  //Global variable to hold the JSON object
  var g_objJSON;

        /** setJSON - Create JSON object
        * Returns - Nothing
        **/
        function setJSON() {
            var v_aJSON = [];
            var v_hObject = {};
            var v_hTempHash = {};

            var v_sKey = document.getElementById("user_email").value;
     // v_sKey = $_SESSION['user_email'];
            var v_sValue = document.getElementById("user_password").value;

            try {
                v_hObject[v_sKey] = v_sValue;

                document.getElementById("user_email").value = "";
                document.getElementById("user_password").value = "";

                if (g_objJSON == undefined) {
                    v_aJSON.push(v_hObject);
                } else {
                    v_hTempHash = mergeHashOb(g_objJSON[0], v_hObject);
                    v_aJSON.push(v_hTempHash);
                }
        g_objJSON = v_aJSON;
        alert("JSON created!");
        for (var item in g_objJSON[0]) {
            console.log("Email: " + item + "\nPassword: " +   g_objJSON[0][item]);
            $.ajax({
              url: '<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/json.php'; ?>',
              type: 'POST',
              data: {json: JSON.stringify(g_objJSON)},
              dataType: 'json'
            });
        }
            } catch (x) {
                alert(x.message);
      }
    }
    /** mergeHashOb - Merge a new JSON object with the global JSON object
               * @prm_hObj - Existing Hash object
               * @prm_hObj2 - New Hash object
               * Returns - A new Hash object contains the merged Hash objects
               **/
               function mergeHashOb(prm_hObj, prm_hObj2) {
                       var v_hObj = {};
                       /*for (var item in prm_hObj) { 
                               v_hObj[item] = prm_hObj[item]; 
                       }*/
                       for (var item in prm_hObj2) { 
                               v_hObj[item] = prm_hObj2[item]; 
                       }
                       return v_hObj;
               }

  function getJSON() {
    var v_hNewHashObj = {};
    var v_aJSON = [];
    var v_sKey = document.getElementById("signin_email").value;
    console.log('signin email: ' + v_sKey);
    var dataString = 'email2='+ v_sKey;
    var v_sValue = document.getElementById("signin_password").value;
    for (var item in g_objJSON[0]){
      if(item == v_sKey) {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: '<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/form-login.php'; ?>',
          data: dataString,
          success: function(result){
            alert(result);
          }
        });
        v_hNewHashObj[item] = g_objJSON[0][item];
        //console.log('getJson: ' + $_POST['signin_email']);
        alert("Welcome "+ v_sKey +". You are logged in.");
        $('#loginModal').hide();
        $('#myModal').hide();
        $('.modal-backdrop').hide();
        $('#openday_events').show();
        break;
      }
      else{
        alert("Login details incorrect");
      }
    }
    v_aJSON.push(v_hNewHashObj);
    g_objJSON = v_aJSON;
  }

  function setEventJSON() {
            var v_aJSON = [];
            var v_hObject = {};
            var v_hTempHash = {};

        //if(isset($_POST)){
          //$v_sKey = $_POST['signin_email'];
         // $_SESSION['userEmail'] = $v_sKey;
        //}

        //var v_sKey = '';
        var v_sKey = '<?php echo (isset($_SESSION['userEmail'])) ? $_SESSION['userEmail'] : ''; ?>';
        //echo $_SESSION['userEmail'];
        //var dataString = 'email2='+ v_sKey;
        console.log(v_sKey);

        //console.log('setEventJSON: ' + $v_sKey);
        var v_sValue = $("div.product-description").attr("data-name");
            //var v_sValue = $("p.product-price").attr("data-name");
            try {
                v_hObject[v_sKey] = v_sValue;

                //$("div.product-description").attr("data-name") = "";
                //$("p.product-price").attr("data-name") = "";

                if (g_objJSON == undefined) {
                    v_aJSON.push(v_hObject);
                } else {
                    v_hTempHash = mergeHashOb(g_objJSON[0], v_hObject);
                    v_aJSON.push(v_hTempHash);
                }
        g_objJSON = v_aJSON;
        alert("Events JSON created!");
        for (var item in g_objJSON[0]) {
            console.log("Email: " + item + "\nEvent Name: " +   g_objJSON[0][item]);
            $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/json-2.php'; ?>',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {json: JSON.stringify(g_objJSON)},
            dataType: 'json'
        });

        }
    alert('saving event');
    $('#my_banner').show();
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#my_banner").offset().top},
      'slow');

    } 

  catch (x) {
                alert(x.message);
      }
      //console.log($(this).serializeArray());
      //event.preventDefault();
    }

</script>
</head>
<body class="landing-page">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-md" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; margin-top: 1em; display: block;">Create Day Plan</button>

<div id="myModal" class="popup--register modal" role="dialog">
    <div class="popup__content">
            <h3>Create your own plan</h3>
    <!--<span onclick="document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
    -->
    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" class="" data-remote="true" action="" id="new_user" method="post">

          <ol class="form-list">
                <li class="form-list__item--full">
                        <input class="mko-signin-capture" id="user_full_name" mko-label="FirstName" name="user[full_name]" placeholder="Full Name*" type="text" required>
                </li>
                <li class="form-list__item--full">
                        <input class="mko-signin-capture" id="user_email" mko-label="Email" name="user[email]" placeholder="Email*" type="text" value="" required>
                      </li>
                <li class="form-list__item--full">
                            <input id="user_password" name="user[password]" placeholder="Password*" type="password" required>
                          </li>
                <li class="form-list__item--full">
                                <input autocomplete="off" id="user_password_confirmation" name="user[password_confirmation]" placeholder="Confirm password*" type="password" required>
                              </li>
                <li class="form-list__item--full">
                                    <div class="selector fixedWidth" id="uniform-user_lead_type_id">
                                        <select class="mko-signin-capture" id="user_lead_type_id" mko-label="Lead_Type__c" name="user[lead_type_id]" required><option value="">I am... *</option>
                              <option data-slug="School Leaver" value="1">A secondary school student</option>
                              <option data-slug="TAFE Student" value="2">A TAFE student</option>
                              <option data-slug="University Student" value="3">A university student</option>
                              <option data-slug="Employed" value="4">In the workforce</option>
                              <option data-slug="Parent" value="5">A parent</option>
                              <option data-slug="Other" value="6">Other</option></select></div>
                                  </li>
                                  <li class="form-list__item--full">
                                        <div class="selector fixedWidth">
                                            <select class="mko-signin-capture" mko-label="Campus__c" id="campus_id">
                                          <option value="">Select a campus...</option>
                                          <option value="Melbourne Burwood">Melbourne Burwood</option>
                                          <option value="Geelong Waterfront">Geelong Waterfront</option>
                                          <option value="Geelong Waurn Ponds">Geelong Waurn Ponds</option>
                                          <option value="Warrnambool">Warrnambool</option>
                                        </select></div>
                                      </li>

    <li class="form-list__item--full">
            <button class="button create-account-button create-account-main" name="button" id="" onclick="setJSON();">CREATE AN ACCOUNT</button>
          </li>
            </ol>
    </form>
    <div class="popup-links">
            <span>Already a member?</span>
            <a href="#" class="popup-link day-plan-login-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal" data-dismiss="#myModal">Login</a>
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Login popup-->
<div class="popup--login modal" role="dialog" id="loginModal">
  <div class="popup__content">
   <!-- <a href="#" class="close-popup mobile">×</a>-->
    <h3>Create your own plan</h3>
    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="" class="new_session" data-remote="true" id="new_user" method="post"><div style="display:none"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"></div>

<!-- Hidden field to store selected info session -->
<input class="new_session_info_session" id="user_info_session" name="user[info_session]" type="hidden">

<ol class="form-list">
<li class="form-list__item--full">
<input class="session_email" id="signin_email" name="signin_email" placeholder="Email*" type="text" value="">
<!--<span class="greeting active">Cool!</span>-->
</li>
<li class="form-list__item--full">
<input class="session_password" id="signin_password" name="signin_password" placeholder="Password*" type="password">
<!--<span class="greeting active">Nicely done!</span>-->
</li>
<li class="form-list__item--full">
<button class="button day-planner-main-login" name="button" type="submit" id="login" onclick="getJSON();">Login</button>
</li>
</ol>
</form>
    <div class="popup-links">
      <a href="#" class="popup-link be-a-grey-link forgotten-pass-link" data-target="popup--reset" data-close="popup--login">Forgotten password?</a>
      <a href="#" class="popup-link create-account-link" id="create-account-popup-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-dismiss="#loginModal">Create an account</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="popup__overlay"></div>
</div>
<!-- Events information-->
<div class="open-day-index-wrap container" id="openday_events" style="display: none;">

  <div class="open-day-index">
    <ol class="open-day-list">
      <li class="open-day-list__item open-day-list--warrnambool">
  <a class="open-day-list__link warrnambool" href="#" id="wrnmbool_events">
    <!--<span class="open-day-list__link warrnambool">-->
    <div class="open-day-image"></div>
    <h5 class="open-day-title" style="color: #fff;">Warrnambool</h5>
    <div class="open-day-date-time-wrap" style="color: #fff;">
      <span class="open-day-date">
        <span class="open-day-date__day">06</span>
        <span class="open-day-date__month">Aug</span>
        <span class="open-day-date__year">2018</span>
      </span>
      <span class="open-day-time"> 9:00 AM -  3:00 PM</span>
      <span class="plan-my-day full-width">
        <span class="plan-my-day__text warrnambool">
          See Events<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></span>
      </span>
    </div><!--endDiv open-day-date-time-wrap-->
    <!--</span>-->
  </a>
</li>
<li class="open-day-list__item open-day-list--geelong-waurn-ponds">
  <a href="/campuses/geelong-waurn-ponds" class="open-day-list__link geelong-waurn-ponds">
    <!--<span class="open-day-list__link geelong-waurn-ponds">-->
    <div class="open-day-image"></div>
    <h5 class="open-day-title" style="color: #fff;">Geelong Waurn Ponds</h5>
    <div class="open-day-date-time-wrap" style="color: #fff;">
      <span class="open-day-date">
        <span class="open-day-date__day">20</span>
        <span class="open-day-date__month">Aug</span>
        <span class="open-day-date__year">2018</span>
      </span>
      <span class="open-day-time"> 9:00 AM -  3:00 PM</span>
      <span class="plan-my-day full-width">
        <span class="plan-my-day__text geelong-waurn-ponds">
          See Events<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></span>
      </span>
    </div><!--endDiv open-day-date-time-wrap-->
    <!--</span>-->
  </a>
</li>
<li class="open-day-list__item open-day-list--geelong-waterfront">
  <a href="/campuses/geelong-waterfront" class="open-day-list__link geelong-waterfront">
    <!--<span class="open-day-list__link geelong-waterfront">-->
    <div class="open-day-image"></div>
    <h5 class="open-day-title" style="color: #fff;">Geelong Waterfront</h5>
    <div class="open-day-date-time-wrap" style="color: #fff;">
      <span class="open-day-date">
        <span class="open-day-date__day">20</span>
        <span class="open-day-date__month">Aug</span>
        <span class="open-day-date__year">2018</span>
      </span>
      <span class="open-day-time"> 9:00 AM -  3:00 PM</span>
      <span class="plan-my-day full-width">
        <span class="plan-my-day__text geelong-waterfront">
          See Events<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></span>
      </span>
    </div><!--endDiv open-day-date-time-wrap-->
    <!--</span>-->
  </a>
</li>
<li class="open-day-list__item open-day-list--melbourne-burwood">
  <a href="/campuses/melbourne-burwood" class="open-day-list__link melbourne-burwood">
    <!--<span class="open-day-list__link melbourne-burwood">-->
    <div class="open-day-image"></div>
    <h5 class="open-day-title" style="color: #fff;">Melbourne Burwood</h5>
    <div class="open-day-date-time-wrap" style="color: #fff;">
      <span class="open-day-date">
        <span class="open-day-date__day">27</span>
        <span class="open-day-date__month">Aug</span>
        <span class="open-day-date__year">2018</span>
      </span>
      <span class="open-day-time"> 9:00 AM -  3:00 PM</span>
      <span class="plan-my-day full-width">
        <span class="plan-my-day__text melbourne-burwood">
          See Events<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></span>
      </span>
    </div><!--endDiv open-day-date-time-wrap-->
    <!--</span>-->
  </a>
</li>

    </ol>
  </div><!--endDiv open-day-index-->
  <br>
  <ul class="nav-list--login">
      <li class="nav-list__item">
        <a href="/open day planner/welcome.php" class="nav-list__link border-link planner-link">My Planner <span class="planners_counter">0</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-list__item">
        <a class="nav-list__link log-out" data-method="delete" href="/open day planner/logout.php" rel="nofollow">Log out</a>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="site" style="display: none;">
    <header id="masthead">
        <h1>Events</h1>
        <ul class="nav-list--login">
                <li class="nav-list__item">
                  <a href="/open day planner/welcome.php" class="nav-list__link border-link planner-link">My Planner <span id="planners_counter"></span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-list__item">
                  <a class="nav-list__link log-out" data-method="delete" href="/open day planner/logout.php" rel="nofollow">Log out</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
    </header>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="products">
            <ul>
                <li>

                    <div class="product-description" data-name="Finding Accomodation" data-price="Warrnambool">
                        <h3 class="product-name">Finding Accomodation</h3>
                        <p class="product-price" data-price="Warrnambool" id="event-location" data-name="Warrnambool">Warrnambool</p>
                        <p class="product-desc">Ipsum qui id ipsum reprehenderit irure in esse pariatur commodo Lorem. Do exercitation nostrud pariatur minim qui deserunt laboris Lorem dolore. Minim labore aliquip cupidatat in anim aliquip ut cillum ipsum excepteur commodo exercitation aliquip. Ad pariatur consectetur fugiat officia laborum incididunt nostrud ex eiusmod.</p>
                        <!--<p class="product-price">10:00 am</p>-->
                        <form class="add-to-cart" action="" method="post">
                                <label for="qty-1">Time</label>
                                <input type="text" name="qty-1" id="qty-1" class="qty" value="10" />
                            <p><input type="submit" value="Save event" class="btn" onclick="setEventJSON();"/></p>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <div class="product-description" data-name="Money Matters" data-price="Warrnambool">
                        <h3 class="product-name">Money Matters</h3>
                        <p class="product-price">Warrnambool</p>
                        <p class="product-desc">Ipsum qui id ipsum reprehenderit irure in esse pariatur commodo Lorem. Do exercitation nostrud pariatur minim qui deserunt laboris Lorem dolore. Minim labore aliquip cupidatat in anim aliquip ut cillum ipsum excepteur commodo exercitation aliquip. Ad pariatur consectetur fugiat officia laborum incididunt nostrud ex eiusmod.</p>

                        <form class="add-to-cart" action="" method="post">
                                <label for="qty-1">Time</label>
                                <input type="text" name="qty-2" id="qty-2" class="qty" value="10" />
                            <p><input type="submit" value="Save event" class="btn save" /></p>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <div class="product-description" data-name="Pathways to Deakin" data-price="Warrnambool">
                        <h3 class="product-name">Pathways to Deakin</h3>
                        <p class="product-price">Warrnambool</p>
                        <p class="product-desc">Ipsum qui id ipsum reprehenderit irure in esse pariatur commodo Lorem. Do exercitation nostrud pariatur minim qui deserunt laboris Lorem dolore. Minim labore aliquip cupidatat in anim aliquip ut cillum ipsum excepteur commodo exercitation aliquip. Ad pariatur consectetur fugiat officia laborum incididunt nostrud ex eiusmod.</p>

                        <form class="add-to-cart" action="" method="post">
                                <label for="qty-1">Time</label>
                                <input type="text" name="qty-3" id="qty-3" class="qty" value="12" />
                            <p><input type="submit" value="Save event" class="btn save" /></p>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="banner dayplanner-page campus-page" style="display: none;" id="my_banner">
                <div class="container">
                  <h2 class="banner__title">My Planner</h2>
                </div><!--endDiv container-->
        <div class="campus-planner__bar">
                <div class="container">
                  <div class="bar-links">
                    <a href="javascript:window.print()" class="print-plan"><i class="fa fa-print"></i>Print</a>
                    <a href="#" class="popup-link email-my-planner-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#email_popup"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>Email</a>
                  </div><!--endDiv bar-links-->
                </div><!--endDiv container-->
              </div>
              <div id="site">
              <div id="content">

              <form id="shopping-cart" action="" method="post">
                  <table class="shopping-cart">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="col">Event</th>
                      <th scope="col">Location</th>
                      <th scope="col" colspan="2">Time</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                    </tbody>
                  </table>

                  <ul id="shopping-cart-actions">
                    <li>
                      <input type="submit" name="delete" id="empty-cart" class="btn" value="Empty planner" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="" class="btn">Continue browsing</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="logout.php" class="btn">Logout</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </form>

                </div>

                </div>

<script  type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/jquery-3.2.1.min.js'; ?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/custom.js'; ?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/bootstrap.min.js'; ?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/jquery.shop.js'; ?>"></script>
<script>
  $("#wrnmbool_events").click(function(){
    //alert('event clicked');
    $('#site').show();
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#site").offset().top},
      'slow');
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

`

Comment: can you show your related codes file ?

Comment: Shared as above.

Answer (score 0):

You just call `session_start()` in the index.php file and then call the session variable you want `$_SESSION['{your_key}']`

Comment: I have used session_start() at the top of my file. Not working! I also tried including the form-login.php in index.php, but still not working.

Comment: Shared all the relevant code. Please see in description

Comment: add `session_start();` to form-login.php. `print_r($_POST);` to see if the data is posted. Remove `include 'form-login.php'`

Comment: Yes, the data is being posted. I'm getting the input email id as the value in array.

Comment: What I'm doing is setting my session variable on call of `getJson()` and retrieve the variable on `setEventJSON()`. Is that possible within the same php file?

Comment: I believe you have 2 files. Can you post the code as it is from the 2 files without posting it in parts?

Comment: Posted the 2 files `form-login.php` and `index.php` above. Kindly note that I am getting blank value in function `setEventJSON()` for `var v_sKey`.

Comment: That is because the session variable hasn't been set yet. You should see the previous value that was set, once you reload.

Comment: Once I reload, how do I get that previous value?

Comment: Once you reload the value will be set, but you do need to make one change: `var v_sKey = '<?php echo (isset($_SESSION['userEmail'])) ? $_SESSION['userEmail'] : '' ?>';`.

Comment: You can reload inside the success callback for the ajax call: `window.location.reload(); `

Comment: Still gives me blank.

Comment: Upload the updated code. This time include the html form as well

Comment: Uploaded in description.

Comment: You have other javascript errors in your code. You can view them in the console of the web inspector. Add the reload code to reload the index.php page when the login is done. Add it to the success callback of the ajax call: `window.location.reload();`

Answer (score 0):

In  your index.php just write below two line

```
session_start();
$variablename = $_SESSION['userEmail'];
```

Make sure you start session before use it.

Answer (score 0):

$_SESSION is global in php you just need to start session_start() in your login.ohp file before setting data into session and after that you can access session anywhere in you script.

Answer (score 0):

put your session_start() at first line in php file .